# Is it possible to set charset with sequelize migrations?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am working on a project where i had to set charset of database to

> utf8mb4

but there is a problem even though i have defined charset in config file, when i run migrations using sequelize-cli it creates database and tables with

> utf8

here is my config.json file

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "database": "coinscout",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "define": {
      "charset": "utf8mb4",
      "collate": "utf8mb4_general_ci"
    }
  }
}
```

this creates a database with tables in utf8 charset but if i drop the database and run
`db.sequelize.sync();`
from code it correctly creates table with given charset.

So i wanted to know what will be best way to change charset if i am using sequelize-cli to create and run migrations?

Comment: are you using the `db:create` command with the cli? i believe charset and collate are both supported as options: `sequelize  db:create --charset utf8mb4 --collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: @dusthaines Thank you that solved my problem, can you please post this as answer so that i can approve it as approved answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the CLI**

`sequelize db:create --charset utf8mb4 --collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

It can be a bit confusing because it is sometimes ambiguous when working with config and model files at what level the `charset` option applies to.

Answer (score 0):

At table level, when using `createTable()` you have options `charset` and `collate`

```
await queryInterface.createTable('your_table', {
  // fields definitions...
}, {
  // options
  charset: 'utf8',
  collate: 'utf8_general_ci'
});
```

See [doc](https://sequelize.org/api/v7/interfaces/_sequelize_core.index.queryinterfacecreatetableoptions)